# How to change selection tolerance for WMS/WFS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, wfs

Does anyone know if there is any equal function to the selection tolerance (ArcMap) in QGIS. I have a problem activating points in my WMS/WFS. 
The "selection tolerance" function solves the problem in ArcMap (If I raise the pixel numbers there it works), but I would like to find a similar function in QGIS. Does any one know?

Comment: Maybe there is an alternative solution, but for this you need to describe your problem more in detail.

Comment: We have problems to activate the points in the WMS/WFS because they are only a pixl wide in reality. By using the selection tolerence in ArcMap we are able to make the sencitivity area bigger (to add more pixles), and thereby easier to activate the point objects. I would like to find a similar function in QGIS.

Comment: Using parameters available to a standard WMS, for a GetFeatureInfo request there is no option for a client to request anything but a pixel.  Tolerances for what information is returned based on the pixel requested are configured at the server end.